# Best way to cast from Animal[] to Dog[]

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

If Dog enherits from Animal.

And I have a Animal[], that I happen to know contains only dogs. What's the fastest/best way to get my hands on a Dog[] ?   I've used  new ArrayList(oldarray).ToArray(typeof(Dog)); so far, but that feels a bit clumsy, and I'm wondering if there is something more elegant.

UPDATE: Using the .net 2.0 profile. Should have offcourse mentioned this straight away. I hope editing the original question adheres to the stackoverflow netiquette in this case. I'm looking forward to the day where we can upgrade and use Linq.

Bye, Lucas

Answer (score 12):

```
var dog_arr = Array.ConvertAll(animal_arr, x => (Dog) x);
```

Comment: I had to use Array.ConvertAll.  Other than that I really like the elegance of this solution.

Answer (score 6):

Using LINQ this will be

```
oldarray.Cast<Dog>().ToArray();
```

Comment: while this is elegant, it's also very inefficient IMHO

Comment: Is efficiency an opinion? I think the compiler should be able to automatically fix the inefficiency presented here. I also think it won't do it. Rarely matters, luckily.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are able to create it as a Dog[] array in the first place?

Given:

```
interface ICage {
    Animal[] GetAnimals();
}
```

If you instantiate a Animal[] array with Dogs in it, you cannot cast the array:

```
class DogCage : ICage {
    Animal[] GetAnimals() { return new Animal[] { spot, fido }; }
}
```

If you instantiate a Dog[] array with Dogs in it, it can still be returned as Animal[] array, but you can also cast the array back to Dog[].

```
class DogCage : ICage {
    Animal[] GetAnimals() { return new Dog[] { spot, fido }; }
}
```

Now this will work:

```
Dog[] dogs = (Dog[])cage.GetAnimals();
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use a generic collection e.g. List from `System.Collections.Generic` instead of an array then use the following:

```
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
animals.Add(new Dog());
List<Dog> dogs = animals.ConvertAll(delegate(Animal animal) { return (Dog)animal; });
```

If you really needed it in an array you could also do:

```
animals.ConvertAll(delegate(Animal animal) { return (Dog)animal; }).ToArray();
```