# object[] as SomeClass[] is always null

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I came across this strange expression some day, and I think it should work.

```
  var attributes = (new object[]
  {
    new SomeClass(),
  }) as SomeBaseClass[];
```

In this snippet, `SomeClass` inherits `SomeBaseClass`, so I think the cast should be valid.

But in fact, `attributes` is always evaluated to `null`. If I use force cast form, I will get `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you shouldn't be able to cast arrays of any type to another, and is a bad practice to do so. For backward compatibility C# has [array covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572(v=vs.71).aspx), which allows a cast in the opposite direction, but not in the direction you want. To properly convert an array, you have to create another array, as shown in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068120/c-sharp-cast-entire-array):

```
var attributes = (new object[]
{
  new SomeClass(),
}).Cast<SomeBaseClass>().ToArray();
```

#### Why is it bad to be able to cast arrays?

Consider the following example:

```
class A {}
class B : A {}

...

var array_a1 = new A[] { new A(); };
var array_b1 = (B[])array_a; // This is error #1

var array_b2 = new B[] { new B(); };
var array_a2 = (A[])array_b2;
array_a2[0] = new A(); // This is error #2
```

In the case of **error #1**, it is clearly seen that `array_b1` cannot be a valid view of `A[]`, as it could have objects of type A when read. This is a runtime error of `InvalidCastException`, happening at the time of the cast.

In the case of **error #2**, `array_a2` is a valid view of `array_b2`, but only for reading. The cast itself is allowed due to [array covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572(v=vs.71).aspx), but trying to put an element of type A in there will cause a runtime `ArrayTypeMismatchException`, as it would cause `array_b2` to have an element of type A. To ensure this kind of type safety the CLR has to do *runtime type checks on array assignments*, which affects performance.

Answer (score 4):

An `object[]` array can store and retrieve *anything*. It's therefore not possible to just cast it to an array of a more derived type. This is explained in [Cast `List<X>` to `List<Y>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5115299/266143).

Shown there is also the workaround:

```
SomeType[] typedObjects = someObjectArray.Cast<SomeType>().ToArray();
```

Note that this will throw an exception if any of the items in `someObjectArray` cannot be cast to `SomeType`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct behavior. Take a look at the specifications of the `as` operator:

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception. Consider the following example:
>
> ```
> expression as type
> ```
>
> The code is equivalent to the following expression except that the expression variable is evaluated only one time.
>
> ```
> expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null
> ```

Now a conversion from `T` to `U` does **not** imply a conversion from `T[]` to `U[]`: the `as` operator is not an intelligent operator in the sense that for an *array* (or another collection), it will perform an element-wise `as`. It only checks if there is a conversion from `object[]` to `SomeClass[]`, and there is none, so it falls back on the default behavior: return `null`.

Consider the following `csharp` output from Mono's C# interactive shell:

```
$ csharp
Mono C# Shell, type "help;" for help

Enter statements below.
csharp> public class Foo {}
csharp> var attributes = new object[] {new Foo(),new Foo(),}; 
csharp> (Foo[]) attributes
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
  at <InteractiveExpressionClass>.Host (System.Object& $retval) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.Evaluator.Evaluate (System.String input, System.Object& result, System.Boolean& result_set) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharpShell.Evaluate (System.String input) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```