# Convert list of float[] to list of double[]

Tags: c#, list, type-conversion, double

I want to convert a `List<float[]>` to `List<double[]>`

```
List<float[]> f=new List<float[]>();
List<double[]> d=new List<double[]>();

// ...add float arrays to f...

d.AddRange((doulbe[])f); // Cannot convert type float[] to double[]
```

is there a way to cast this? so that it won't require a for loop, because I have many lists to be converted.

Comment: The AddRange is implemented as a for loop. You need to do the same (using a for loop, a linq query or anything that enumerate your collection). You can't do it in place

Comment: `Array.ConvertAll`, which is using a loop under the hood

Comment: Remember that a `float` and a `double` are different sizes. You can't just take the bits from a `float` and re-interpret them as a `double`. This is what you're asking the cast to do however.

Comment: [C# Cast Entire Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068120/c-sharp-cast-entire-array)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Saldly this does not work, you get a InvalidCastException, but it was my first thought as well

Comment: Yeah, remember that you can't use generics to invoke user-defined conversion operators

Comment: @canton7 I am converting from a lower precision to a higher precision, so it does not lose anything from the numbers.

Comment: Right, but my point was that an array cast (strictly, a reference conversion) is a different way of looking at the same underlying bits in memory. You can't take the underlying bits of a float and look at them as if they were a double, so an array cast is not going to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
d.AddRange(f.Select(flArray => Array.ConvertAll(flArray, f => (double)f)));
```

or:

```
f.ForEach(flArray => d.Add(Array.ConvertAll(flArray, f => (double)f)));
```