# Convert an array of object to a list of a class

Tags: c#

I have an array of objects like:

```
object[]
```

All elements of the array if compatible with a type, that I will call

```
MyClass
```

How can I convert this object[] to a List ?

Comment: `yourArray.Cast<MyClass>().ToList()`, if all objects in the `object[]` are `MyClass` instances, or `yourArray.OfType<MyClass>().ToList()` if the `object[]` is heterogenous and you want to select `MyClass` instances.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, that is it. Perfectly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Cast Entire Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068120/c-sharp-cast-entire-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `Cast` and `OfType` methods, depending on what you want to happen if your array contains an element that is *not* of type `MyClass`.

If you want to throw an exception upon encountering an invalid element, use:

```
var myList = myArray.Cast<MyClass>().ToList();
```

If you want to silently ignore all items that are not `MyClass`, use:

```
var myList = myArray.OfType<MyClass>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to achieve this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;                  
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        object[] l = new object[3];
        l[0] = new MyClass();
        l[1] = new MyClass();
        l[2] = new NotMyClass();
        var res = l.Where(e => e is MyClass).Cast<MyClass>();
        foreach(var e in res){
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass{
}

public class NotMyClass{
    
}
```